Movie from the fifties where aliens look human but wear sunglasses to hide that they have no irises (color) in their eyes - only whites!
Been looking for decades. A probably black and white movie wherein guys from outer space come to Earth to convert the earthlings into themselves (typical). But, these guys look human, only they wear sunglasses to hide the fact that they have no irises on their eyeballs -- only whites. They worked in pairs and wore dark suits, so kind of like the Blues Brothers. When they wanted to "get" an earthling, they'd pull 'em into an alley, alone, take off their sunglasses to reveal only whites, stare into the eyes of the victim who would lose their irises and become one of them. I really don't remember any more about the plot. It scared me so bad I had to sleep with my mom three nights because I was sure the "Guys with the bald-headed eyeballs" were in my closet.

I haven't seen it myself to be sure, but possibly "Not Of This Earth" from 1957? It doesn't sound like an exact match, but some aspects line up. The Wikipedia plot summary describes it thus:

A man who is "not of this Earth" has adopted the name "Mr. Johnson" for moving among the populace of Los Angeles. The alien has a sensitivity to high-decibel sounds and is conspicuous only for his stilted and formal syntax and his sunglasses, which he wears even in the dark. The sunglasses hide his blank, white-eyed stare which kills his victims by burning through their eyes and into their brains.

IMDb has a photo showing a dark suit and sunglasses.
